# lualatex luaotfload | load : path lookup of "latinmodern-math.otf" unsuccessful

Tags: latex

### This is on fedora 24 (texlive 2015)

```
lualatex test.test
...
luaotfload | load : path lookup of "latinmodern-math.otf" unsuccessful, falling 
back to file:(compiling luc: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/f
onts/otf/latinmodern-math.luc)(load luc: /home/nbecker/.texlive2015/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/latinmodern-math.luc)
luaotfload | load : path lookup of "latinmodern-math.otf" unsuccessful, falling 
back to file:
...
```

### (eventually, missing glyphs...)

But:

```
luaotfload-tool --find=latinmodern-math.otf
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc,dfont); reason: "Font latinmodern-math.otf not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : Cannot find "latinmodern-math.otf" in index.
luaotfload | resolve : Hint: use the --fuzzy option to display suggestions.
[nbecker@nbecker2 interference]$ luaotfload-tool --find=latinmodern-math.otf --fuzzy
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc,dfont); reason: "Font latinmodern-math.otf not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : Cannot find "latinmodern-math.otf" in index.
luaotfload | resolve : Hint: use the --fuzzy option to display suggestions.
luaotfload | resolve : Looking for close matches, this may take a while ...
luaotfload | query : Distance from "latinmodernmathotf": 7
    LatinModernMath-Regular
    LatinModernMath-Regular
[nbecker@nbecker2 interference]$ luaotfload-tool --find=latinmodern-math --fuzzy
luaotfload | resolve : Font "latinmodern-math" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/usr/share/fonts/lm-math/latinmodern-math.otf"
```

Is it possible that lualatex is looking for 'latinmodern-math.otf' which fails, when it should be looking for 'latinmodern-math', which succeeds?  If so, why and how do I fix it?

Comment: I see that if I edit the file unicode-math-lualatex.sty, to change: "latinmodern-math.otf" to "latinmodern-math", I no longer get the message  luaotfload | load : path lookup of "latinmodern-math.otf" unsuccessful, falling 
back to file:  I wonder if this file has a typo?  OTOH, I still see the messages about Missing character: There is no  (U+1D454) in font "file:lmsans10-regular:scr
ipt=latn;+trep;+tlig;"!

Comment: I've added a minimal test case here that shows the 'missing character:' https://gist.github.com/nbecker/5cc8ae052a80b3db6e9ec6b094639318